# Автоматическая авторизация Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

У меня следующая проблема: есть  два приложения Oracle Apex, которые находятся в разных workspace: каждое из которых имеет свой собственный вход в систему и собственную схему базы данных. Чтобы упростить задачу конечному пользователю, я хотел бы реализовать автоматическую авторизацию из app1 в app2. Сейчас пользователь может перейти только на страницу авторизации app2. Есть ли какие-нибудь рекомендации по решению данной проблемы и возможно ли это вообще?